# How to export file names and urls from s3 to csv?

Tags: amazon-s3, export-to-csv

Is it possible to export all the files and their URLs from an S3 bucket to csv file?
I tried using this [tool](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html) but it doesn't export URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible using the [Get Bucket command from the REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html). But you'll need to do something programmatically to parse the response for your asset names formatted into your CSV as you like. Since there is an API available most tools out there (like the one you've found) are not super rich with features.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2009 17:50:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:xQE0diMbLRepdf3YB+FIEXAMPLE=
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Response example:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
> <Name>bucket</Name>
> <Prefix/>
> <Marker/>
> <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
> <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
> <Contents>
>     <Key>my-image.jpg</Key>
>     <LastModified>2009-10-12T17:50:30.000Z</LastModified>
>     <ETag>&quot;fba9dede5f27731c9771645a39863328&quot;</ETag>
>     <Size>434234</Size>
>     <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
>     <Owner>
>         <ID>75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a</ID>
>         <DisplayName>mtd@amazon.com</DisplayName>
>     </Owner>
> </Contents>
> <Contents>
>    <Key>my-third-image.jpg</Key>
>      <LastModified>2009-10-12T17:50:30.000Z</LastModified>
>     <ETag>&quot;1b2cf535f27731c974343645a3985328&quot;</ETag>
>     <Size>64994</Size>
>     <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
>     <Owner>
>         <ID>75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a</ID>
>         <DisplayName>mtd@amazon.com</DisplayName>
>     </Owner>
> </Contents> </ListBucketResult>
> ```

Comment: i know we can get this via APIs. I was looking for some tools.

Comment: Take a developer out for a beer. It will be easy to write this. Maybe 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might help. Wrote a quick JS script to export the objects in an S3 Bucket to a JSON file instead of XML. Hope it helps!

https://github.com/springerkc/s3-bucket-exporter